# Powershell variable increment pipe to file problem

Tags: powershell

I am writing a powershell script to carry out many things then reboot and carry on from a same position using runonce and a variable incremented to return to the correct phase of the script but I have come across some weird results whilst testing...

```
$phase = 0
$phasePath = C:[blah]\test.txt

$phase++ | out-file -filepath $phasePath
```

The $phase increment and pipe is part of a function that is run before rebooting but even with a simple test like above when the `$phase++ | out-file -filepath $phasePath` is run $phase is incremented but 0 is still present in the file (which is written to earlier in the script).  When I run the command again I get 1 in the file and the value of $phase is 2.  What am I doing wrong???  Thanks in advance

Comment: Change `$phase++` to `($phase++)` (you probably want `(++$phase)` though)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is mostly with pre-increment vs post-incrementing a value. Powershell's `++` operator sets the target value, but the value it passes along the pipeline is either pre or post-increment based on where the `++` appears:

```
# Pre-Increment
$phase = 0
$phase++ | Out-Host  # outputs 0
$phase  # outputs 1

# Post-Increment
$phase = 0
++phase | Out-Host  # outputs 1
```

Note that `++` doesn't output to the console, just the pipeline. You can force it to output normally by enclosing it in parentheses, but the pre/post rule still applies:

```
$phase = 0
$phase++  # outputs nothing
($phase++)  # outputs 1, but now $phase=2
(++$phase)  # outputs 3
```

Comment: Yep this works... Never even knew of pre and post increments.  Every day is a schools day.  Many thanks for your help Cpt.Whale and  @Mathias R. Jessen